# Creating VM instances is time consuming in GCP. How to avoid?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine

I'm new to Google cloud platform and I realize that I have to create a new VM every time I want to compute some AI calculations or ipython notebook analysis.

I realise that the creation of the VM takes about 3 minutes and I wonder how do people in the industry do. Do you guys waste those 3 minutes everytime you start a new work ?

Do you create a new VM every morning for the day ?
Can you keep the instance running overnight ? I believe I have understood that you need to delete the instance everytime you stop using it to avoid unnecessary costs.

On top of that, does it mean you need to save all your work to Google cloud storage everytime you finish a work in order to reload it on the next VM instance the next day ?

This all seems to me to be complicated and I wonder if there are some simpler ways of doing it.

Comment: The approach you choose to take (imo) depends largely on the project in question, how much you plan on doing it in the future etc. You may consider finding a way to dockerize your computational workload and running it in [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) (serverless) which starts very quickly, and ends when your workload has finished processing. Like I mentioned, whether that is actually a good approach for you depends largely on the details of your workload.

Comment: I have never deleted a VM and recreated it in the morning to save money. We do run scripts to shut down and restart development VMs during off-hours. In the environments I work in, the cost of VMs is apx 10% of our total spend. Database, networking, backups/snapshots and Cloud Storage are the big-ticket items. Your workflow is not what typical developers do even when on a budget.

Comment: Does the VM still cost money when it is paused ?

Comment: Stop the VM -> You will pay only the persistent disk. Pause the VM -> You will pay only the persistent disk and the memory of your instance. Delete your VM, you will no longer pay for the CPU, the Memory and the persistent disk

Comment: The best tradeoff between money saving and overwhelming process is to stop the VM when you no longer use it. Use a reasonable persistent disk size and store your data on Cloud Storage (for large training, only get a subset on your VM to design/test your model)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the VM creation operation may take about 3 minutes. Further, keeping the VM in a stooped state might reduce the costs, However, it still charges for Persistent disks, Static IP addresses and Any other resources associated with the instance, such as external IP addresses, GPUs, etc.

Additionally, you may consider [saving money by stopping and starting Compute Engine instances on schedule](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/save-money-by-stopping-and-starting-compute-engine-instances-on-schedule).